# Python Histograms Using Grouped Data

Tags: python, group-by, histogram

I am looking to make Histograms for each group in my grouped data set. Right now it is only producing one graph(and quite honestly i'm not sure what group it even is). There are 21 groups and I want to make one for each, what would I add to my current code so that I can get a graph for each group in my grouped data.

I am also trying to figure out how to get the total number of patients in the group, the mean, and std for each group and place it at the top (see chart title).

Any help would be appreciated :)

```
#histogram
ric_group_ser = pd.Series()
#split on RIC
grouped_by_ric = cleaned_data_df.groupby('RIC')
#apply age to RIC column
for group_name, group_df in grouped_by_ric:
    grouped_ric= group_df['Age']
    print(grouped_ric)

hist_plot =grouped_ric.hist(bins=30, facecolor="green", edgecolor="black")
#plt.annotate("mean: %.2f" %(np.mean(data_df)), xy=(105.0, 85.0))
plt.title("Age Histogram:<RIC> Age (N=<total>): Mean: <2 decimal places>, StdDev: <2 decimal places>")
plt.xlabel("Age(years)")
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
plt.grid(False)

#plt.savefig("Histogram")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Are you looking to create 21 distinct plots?  Or one "plot" with 21 subplots?  Or one plot with 21 sets of bars (can't imagine this would work out for you)?

Comment: I am looking to create 21 different plots, one for group in the grouped data. I should have 21 graphs total